# Unity 7 window spread lag

Tags: unity, nvidia, compiz

On my Ubuntu 16.04 box when I press Ctrl+w it sometimes takes up to 1 second before the window spread animation starts. The animation itself is usually smooth though. The issue is not a hardware issue as the rest of the system is very smooth and responsive, only the window spread effect is slow. This is on a laptop with i7 quad core, 32 GB ddr4 ram, nVidia GTX 980m with 8gb vram using binary driver, laptop monitor running at 1080p plus external monitors running at 1200p. Any idea how to fix this?